# High memory usage with Files.lines

Tags: java

I've found a few other questions on SO that are close to what I need but I can't figure this out. I'm reading a text file line by line and getting an out of memory error. Here's the code:

```
System.out.println("Total memory before read: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1000000 + "MB");
String wp_posts = new String();
try(Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
    wp_posts = stream
            .filter(line -> line.startsWith("INSERT INTO `wp_posts`"))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append,
                    StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 

try {
    System.out.println("wp_posts Mega bytes: " + wp_posts.getBytes("UTF-8").length/1000000);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("Total memory after read: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1000000 + "MB");
```

Output is like (when run in an environment with more memory):

```
Total memory before read: 255MB
wp_posts Mega bytes: 18
Total memory after read: 1035MB
```

Note than in my production environment, I cannot increase the memory heap.

I've tried explicitly closing the stream, doing a gc, and putting stream in parallel mode (consumed more memory).

My questions are:
Is this amount of memory usage expected?
Is there a way to use less memory?

Comment: You should expect memory usage to be correlated with the size of the content you're loading in memory. If it's a problem to load the entire file in memory the way you're doing, you may need to simply process the file in smaller chunks/batches.

Comment: I suspect the `StringBuilder` is causing the issue. Also how big is your file exactly?

Comment: The file is almost 300Mb.

Comment: @ScottBrodersen You need to redesign your method to make it process reasonable numbers of lines at a time. Maybe including the actual processing of the string builder in the question can get you practical answers/solutions.

Comment: @ernest_k I thought that Files.lines() reads the file line by line to avoid reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: No, that's why things like BufferedReader exist. Which, by the way, now can return a stream as well (though I'm not sure of its performance.)

Comment: It does indeed read the file line by line.  You are then accumulating all of those lines into a StringBuilder, so naturally they continue to take up memory.

Comment: @ScottBrodersen `Files.lines` reads the file line by line indeed, **but you are collecting the entire content in an in-memory buffer**, which will end up using memory for the entire file

Comment: I don't understand these comments that indicate the entire file is stored in the BufferedReader (not saying you're wrong, just that they conflict with my current understanding (which may be wrong)). The lines are filtered before being stored, so only a subset of lines are stored. I have verified that the end-result reflects this.

Comment: @ScottBrodersen Filtering is fine. But even after filtering if you have significant number of lines, it'll cause out of memory which is in fact happening as you have confirmed. So, for the sake of simplicity everyone is ignoring the filter part. I've also ignored the filter part in my example below.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append)`. When you add smth to the `StringBuilder` and it has not enough internal array, then it double it and copy part from previous one.

Do `new StringBuilder(int size)` to predefine size of internal array.

Second problem, is that you have a big file, but as result you put it into a `StringBuilder`. This is very strange to me. Actually this is same as read whole file into a `String` without using `Stream`.

Comment: I'm filtering the lines before adding to the StringBuilder, so only a subset of the lines are being stored. I changed the code to process each line as it is read instead of storing them in the StringBuilder, but this had no effect. As soon as the stream is done with the file, the used memory doubles.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Runtime.totalMemory()` calculation is pointless if you are allowing JVM to resize the heap. Java will allocate heap memory as needed as long as it doesn't exceed `-Xmx` value. Since JVM is smart it won't allocate heap memory by 1 byte at a time because it would be very expensive. Instead JVM will request a larger amount of memory at a time (actual value is platform and JVM implementation specific).

Your code is currently loading the content of the file into memory so there will be objects created on the heap. Because of that JVM most likely will request memory from the OS and you will observer increased `Runtime.totalMemory()` value.

Try running your program with strictly sized heap e.g. by adding `-Xms300m -Xmx300m` options. If you won't get `OutOfMemoryError` then decrease the heap until you get it. However you also need to pay attention to GC cycles, these things go hand in had and are a trade off.

Alternatively you can create a heap dump after the file is processed and then explore the data with [MemoryAnalyzer](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Comment: I'm running this in my test env -- spitting out the totalMemory is only to get an idea of how much memory is being used and when. I indicated that in my production environment I cannot adjust the heap size (sorry if that wasn't clear).

Thank you for the suggestion of analyzing the heap dump.

Answer (score 0):

The way you calculated memory is incorrect due to the following reasons:

1. You have taken the total memory (*not* the used memory). JVM allocates memory lazily and when it does, it does it in chunks. So, when it needs an additional 1 byte memory, it may allocate 1MB memory (provided the total memory does not exceed the configured max heap size). Thus a good portion of allocated heap memory may remain unused. Therefore, you need to calculate the used memory: `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`
2. A good portion of the memory you see with the above formula maybe ready for garbage collection. JVM would definitely do the garbage collection before saying OutOfMemory. Therefore, to get an idea, you should do a `System.gc()` before calculating used memory. Ofcourse, you don't call gc in production and also calling gc does not guarantee that JVM would indeed trigger garbage collection. But for testing purpose, I think it works well.
3. You got the OutOfMemory when the stream processing was in progress. At that time the `String` was not formed and the `StringBuilder` had strong reference. You should call the `capacity()` method of `StringBuilder` to get the actual number of `char` elements in the array within `StringBuilder` and then multiply it by 2 to get the number of bytes because Java internally uses `UTF16` which needs 2 bytes to store an ASCII character.
4. Finally, the way your code is written (i.e. not specifying a big enough size for `StringBuilder` initially), every time your `StringBuilder` runs out of space, it double the size of the internal array by creating a new array and copying the content. This means there will be triple the size allocated at a time than the actual `String`. This you cannot measure because it happens within the `StringBuilder` class and when the control comes out of `StringBuilder` class the old array is ready for garbage collection. So, there is a high chance that when you get the OutOfMemory error, you get it at that point in `StringBuilder` when it tries to allocate a double sized array, or more specifically in the `Arrays.copyOf` method

### How much memory is expected to be consumed by your program as is? (A rough estimate)

Let's consider the program which is similar to yours.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
  // Initialize the arraylist to emulate a 
  // file with 32 lines each containing
  // 1000 ASCII characters
  List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>(32);
  for (Integer i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    strList.add(String.format("%01000d", i));
  }


  StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
  strList.stream().map(element -> {
    // Print the number of char
    // reserved by the StringBuilder
    System.out.print(str.capacity() + ", ");
    return element;
  }).collect(() -> {
    return str;
  }, (response, element) -> {
    response.append(element);
  }, (response, element) -> {
    response.append(element);
  }).toString();
}
```

Here after every append, I'm printing the capacity of the `StringBuilder`.

The output of the program is as follows:

```
16, 1000, 2002, 4006, 4006, 8014, 8014, 8014, 8014, 
16030, 16030, 16030, 16030, 16030, 16030, 16030, 16030, 
32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 
32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 32062, 32062,
```

If your file has "n" lines (where n is a power of 2) and each line has an average "m" ASCII characters, the capacity of the `StringBuilder` at the end of the program execution will be: (n * m + 2 ^ (a + 1) ) where (2 ^ a = n).

E.g. if your file has 256 lines and an average of 1500 ASCII characters per line, the total capacity of the `StringBuilder` at the end of program will be: (256 * 1500 + 2 ^ 9) = 384512 characters.

Assuming, you have only ASCII characters in you file, each character will occupy 2 bytes in UTF-16 representation. Additionally, everytime when the `StringBuilder` array runs out of space, a new bigger array twice the size of original is created (see the capacity growth numbers above) and the content of the old array is copied to the new array. The old array is then left for garbage collection. Therefore, if you add another 2 ^ (a+1) or 2 ^ 9 characters, the `StringBuilder` would create a new array for holding (n * m + 2 ^ (a + 1) ) * 2 + 2 characters and start copying the content of old array into the new array. Thus, there will be two big sized arrays within the `StringBuilder` as the copying activity goes on.

thus the total memory will be: 384512 * 2 + (384512 * 2 + 2 ) * 2 = 23,07,076 = 2.2 MB (approx.) to hold only 0.7 MB data.

I have ignored the other memory consuming items like array header, object header, references etc. as those will be negligible or constant compared to the array size.

**So, in conclusion, 256 lines with 1500 characters each, consumes 2.2 MB (approx.) to hold only 0.7 MB data (one-third data).**

*If you had initialized the `StringBuilder` with the size 3,84,512 at the beginning, you could have accommodated the same number of characters in one-third memory and also there would have been much less work for CPU in terms of array copy and garbage collection*

### What you may consider doing instead

Finally, in such kind of problems, you may want to do it in chunks where you would write the content of your `StringBuilder` in a file or database as soon as it has processed 1000 records (say), clear the `StringBuilder` and start over again for the next batch of records. Thus you'd never hold more than 1000 (say) record worth of data in memory.